# Не подключается php_ldap.dll PHP 7.2.14

Tags: php, apache, ldap

Пытаюсь подключить расширение для ldap для PHP 7.2.14 (Windows 10 64bit).

Пробовал также PHP 7.3 и 7.4.
В php.ini раскомментировал строку extension=ldap.

Путь к каталогу с расширениями указан верно (не работает только ldap).

Пробовал добавлять библиотеки libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll, libsasl.dll во все папки которые только советовали.

Apache перезапускал, компьютер перезагружал, результат тот же.

phpinfo() нет блока ldap.

php -info то же нет блока ldap.

В логах апача

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ldap' (tried: C:\Server\Php7.2\ext\ldap (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Server\Php7.2\ext\php_ldap.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP ставил 64bit, пробовал библиотеку от 32bit версии, не помогло.

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Что в логах сервера по поводу расширения?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ldap' (tried: C:\\Server\\Php7.2\\ext\\ldap (The specified module could not be found.), C:\\Server\\Php7.2\\ext\\php_ldap.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)) in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно выяснить какая конкретно версия PHP у вас, архитектура системы, тип потоконезависимости (threadsafe или нет) и версии VC библиотеки компиляции, и конкретно для этого типа устанавливать библиотеку. У меня, к примеру, в комплекте OpenServer уже есть эта библиотека, и раскомментировав её в php.ini она подключилась без ошибок.

Если вы тоже используете OpenServer, то не редактируйте php.ini напрямую - открывайте его через меню для сервера в tray bar'е.

**Дополнено**

Скачивайте архив с https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/ соответственно своей конфигурации сервера, распаковывайте файл оттуда файл /ext/php_ldap.dll в вашу папку расширений и перезагружайте сервер. После этого проверяйте через phpinfo().

[image: PHPINFO]

Comment: У меня без openserver
По настройкам также как у вас, только версия php 7.2.14

Comment: Добавьте изображение аналогично моему в свой вопрос, и сообщите какой сервер у вас (проверьте что это точно Apache, а не, к примеру, IIS).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я обновил пхп до 7.2.27 и все сразу заработало.